# Why is my function only working for the first element of the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I just started learning Python recently. I want to calculate the frequency of each character in a list. However, my code only works for the first element in the list.

my code:

```
import sys

n = [str(s) for s in sys.argv[1].split()]

def countLetter(n):
    frequencyLetter = {}
    for word in n:
        for letter in word:
            keys = frequencyLetter.keys()
            if letter in keys:
                frequencyLetter[letter] += 1
            else:
                frequencyLetter[letter] = 1
    return frequencyLetter

print(countLetter(n))
```

the result:

```
C:\Users\john\pythonlearn\testing> main.py hello, there
{'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1, ',': 1}
```

It should be calculating the frequency of characters for both "hello" and "there". I don't know why there's a ---->  ',':1  <---- in the output.

Comment: Because you are iterating over the whole string `hello, there`, including the `,`

Comment: Your first argument is `"hello,"`, command-line arguments are separated by a space, not a `,`

Comment: Because 'hello,' is in argv[1] and 'there' is in argv[2].

Comment: Instead of `n`, just use `sys.argv[1:]`. No need to use `split` or `str`.

Comment: When you printed stuff at different places in your program could you *see* where it might be going wrong? Like maybe add `print(f'n: {n}')` just before `print(countLetter(n))` - and maybe some more in the function.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems here:

1. You are parsing your list of arguments in the wrong way.
2. No need to manually increment a counter. The `Counter` class from `collections` will do fine here:

```py
import sys
from collections import Counter

arglist = sys.argv[1:]  # exclude filename

def count_letters(args):
    # Results will be stored in a dict
    res = {}
    for word in args:
        x = Counter(word)
        res.update(x)
    return res

res = count_letters(arglist)
print(res)
```

Also, given it seems you **really** want to check for commas in you arguments (even if you can easily avoid this condition by separating them with a space), you can strip them out before adding them to the `Counter` object:

```py
def count_letters(args):
    # Results will be stored in a dict
    res = {}
    for word in args:
        # If a comma is found, strip it out
        if "," in word:
            word = word.replace(",", "")
        x = Counter(word)
        res.update(x)
    return res
```

Calling the script with `python parse.py hello there` or `python parse.py hello, there` will give the same following result:

```
{'h': 1, 'e': 2, 'l': 2, 'o': 1, 't': 1, 'r': 1}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed explanation. it has been very helpful in helping me to understand where I went wrong. I would like to ask if there's a way where the code will not count the frequency of the comma? cause I want to call the script as such ---> "python parse.py hello,there" instead

Comment: No worries, happy to help. You **don't** need to separate command line arguments with a comma when calling the function. Why would you want to call it that way?

Comment: I'm curious whether it is possible to do it in case i want to input multiple words. However, I can't seem to make the code ignore the comma..

Comment: That is what just happened in the example above. You can separate multiple words with a space and it'll work just fine. If you really want to exclude commas you just add an `if` condition when passing the word to the counter (skipping if it's ","). But again, I would just pass arguments the right way.

Comment: Pretty sure the comprehension *converting* to strings is not necessary.

Comment: @John If the answer above is what you're after consider to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow) it as an answer.